# How can I reduce flicker on an ELV chandelier?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, dimmer-switch, neutral

I wired up a set of ELV lights in my dining room and used this particular dimmer switch (Lutron MRF2-6ELV-120-WH) at the switch box.

The wiring was rather straightforward. No more complicated than the attached image. At the switch box, I had everything I needed. Line, load and neutral. The light, though, has a noticable flicker--not too bad when it is turned on full, but when dimmed becomes quite noticeable, especially around 20%. The flicker 
seems to be about 3-4Hz.

The common consenus seems to be that I didn't properly use the neutral wire, but I am quite sure I did.

Furthermore, I have contacted the manufacturer of the light directly, and asked them if it is known to have any issues with the switch I chose. They actually set up the exact configuration on their test bench and told me that the lights are 100% compatible with the switch and that they had no detectable flicker.

**What might I be able to do, if anything, to reduce the flicker?**

Is the issue in the integrity of the neutral wire? Is there anything I can do to test that it is properly wired to the breaker box and that there are no "leaks" to ground or elsewhere? Would that even cause the flicker?

Here is an example of a similar wiring situation:

[image]

Additional info:

[These are the lights](http://kuzcolighting.com/specsheets/402105CH-LED%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf), there is no additional transformer. It is all built into the chandelier.

Comment: lutron says the minimum load is 5w, is it possible you've less than that once dimmed? also, is your transformer magnetic? (not solid-state)

Comment: @dandavis. Possibly. Shouldn't the manufacturer's test have had the same issue, though? Can I do something to increase the load?

Comment: you could have some minor line drops that land you on another side of a threshold than their equipment, or you might have a faulty bulb or two.

Comment: @dandavis, no I trust them, they got back to me days later and sent a photo of their test bench including the box the switch came in, they used the exact same switch.

Comment: I dont understand.  You are sending 120V mains power to it.  How can it be ELV if you are not using low voltage?  Is there a conversion box, transformer etc. which turns the mains voltage into low voltage?  How does that power supply feel about its input being dimmed?

Comment: @Harper, my understanding is that ELV dimmers work by altering the phase and the duty cycle of the mains power. It is the electronics in the light that convert that signal to the appropriate low voltage.

Comment: Unless it's plain transformers and incandescents, it's hard to get that to work right.  The switching power supplies have to be pretty smart to infer the correct dimming from distorted  waveforms like that, and at low intensities they just can't.  There are other,  much better ways to dim LEDs.

Comment: Does this dimmer have you wiring in a neutral wire?

Comment: @Harper, yes it absolutely does. A neutral is pigtailed to the others. So the switch has 3 wires: the line, the load and the neutral.

Comment: If you unhook only the load (lamp)  wire  of the dimmer, does the dimmer power up and act normally (outside of having nothing to dim of course)?  I'm fishing for Line/Load reversed. On a neutraled dimmer, it matters.  While you're trying that, try bypassing the dimmer entirely and hardwiring the lamp straight through (always on when breaker on). Does it flicker even slightly then?

Comment: @Harper, well I can tell without a doubt where the live is when the switch is not connected using a non-contact voltage tester. I'll have to try your suggestion later tonight.

Comment: Wiuld just sanity check it if you haven't already, I also want to know how the lamp performs if hotwired in. Anytime you install two new things at once (lamp and dimmer) it's tough to distinguish which is the problem.

Comment: @Harper, I solved the problem. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem, but not the way I expected.

Basically, I used a non-ELV dimmer switch from GE instead. Works much better. I guess the conclusion from this is that the Lutron Maestro is a crappy dimmer. Good thing they discontinued it.